# Operator<< Overloading, endl leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Just moved my program over from windows to linux and the same code that worked now gives me a segmentation fault when calling the operator<< function from main.
(overview) My programs is a Vector class that takes input and returns what the input is, but when reach `<< endl` it crashes, if I remove `endl` from `main()` it does not crash?

```
..///main


VecXd<int> x;                                           
        cout << "Input vector a\n"; 

cin >> a;


cout << "Test A: "<< a << endl; //seg fault, -> 
cout << "Test A: " << a; //works

//----- class VecXd\\ opertor<< def + operator>>

  /******************************************************/
   friend istream &operator>>(istream &input, VecXd& vec)
   {

         for(int i = -1; i <= vec.dimension - 1; i++)
         {
           if(i == -1)
           {
           input >> vec.dimension;//>> (V vecArr = new V[vec.dimension]);
           cout << vec.dimension << " dimension check" << endl;
           vec.vecArr = new V[vec.dimension];
                                //vec.dimension = vecArr[0];
                                //cout << vec.dimension << " dimension check" << endl;
           }
           else
           {
           input >> vec.vecArr[i];//>> (V vecArr = new V[vec.dimension]);
           cout << vec.vecArr[i] << " value check" << endl;
           }
         }


   }

   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const VecXd& vec)
   {
          for(int i = 0; i < vec.dimension; i++)
          {
          output << vec.vecArr[i] << " ";

          }
          output << endl;
         // output << endl;

   }
   /****************************************************/
```

why does endl lead to crash? doesn't end of array outputing endl solve this issue?

Comment: The question is unclear. The crash is most probably not due to the use of `endl`, check whether `vec.vecArr` is a valid pointer and `i` is correct for all inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forget to return `ostream&` (and `istream&`).

Add `-Wall` flag to your compile command if you are using gcc/clang/icc

Comment: Oops, made an accidental edit. Please ignore. Actual comment: I wonder if the OPs compiler puts out a warning about this ...

Comment: thats it! thank Anycom!

Comment: By default gcc doesn't warn about missing returns.  I get bitten by this sometimes.

Comment: @SxMZ np man, i make same mistake once a while.  `-Wall` is really helpful to catch mistakes like this.